# Azure data factory end time trigger

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have one scenario let say I have one ADF instance name XYZ contains one pipeline which is schedule trigger starts at 12:00 AM in night. Trigger some time ends in 1 hours and sometime it takes more than 2 hours because of data load.

I have one more ADF instance ABC in that also one pipeline I have, now my requirement is that I have to schedule the ABC instance pipeline when  xyz instance trigger is completed.

Kindly help on this requirement. Both ADF have different instance & also trigger end time may vary based on load.

Comment: Seems you need to use Tumbling window trigger on ABC instance's pipeline and creates dependency with that for XYZ instance. so that once xyz finishes, then abc would start running, even the end time varies for xyz, this would help.

Comment: Both acb and xyz are in different instance tumbling window won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is using  [Logic app](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/logic-apps/quickstart-create-first-logic-app-workflow). In Logic app designer, we can create two pipeline run steps to trigger the two pipelines in different Data Factory running.

1. Create a **Recurrence** trigger to run this logic app in a loop.
   [image]
2. In the **Azure Data Factory** operations:
   [image]
3. select **Create a pipeline run** Action.
   [image]
4. The summary is here:
   [image]

So we can trigger the pipeline run of the ADF instance name XYZ, and when it is completed, it will trigger the pipeline run of the ADF instance ABC.